# Log4j2 not creating log files

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j2

I am trying out log4j2 configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration status="info">
    <appenders>
        <Console name="console-log" target="SYSTEM_OUT" append="false">
            <ThresholdFilter level="INFO" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %class{36}:%L %M - %msg%xEx%n"/>
        </Console>
        <File name="debug-log" fileName="${catalina.base}/logs/debug.log" append="false">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd 'at' HH:mm:ss.SSS z} %-5level %class{36}:%L %M - %msg%xEx%n"/>
        </File>
        <File name="trace-log" fileName="${catalina.base}/logs/trace.log" append="false">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd 'at' HH:mm:ss.SSS z} %-5level %class{36}:%L %M - %msg%xEx%n"/>
        </File>
        <File name="error-log" fileName="${catalina.base}/logs/error.log" append="false">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd 'at' HH:mm:ss.SSS z} %-5level %class{36}:%L %M - %msg%xEx%n"/>
        </File>
    </appenders>
    <loggers>
        <root level="debug" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="console-log"/>
        </root>
        <Logger name="com.mypackage" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="debug-log" level="debug"/>
            <appender-ref ref="trace-log" level="info"/>
            <appender-ref ref="error-log" level="error"/>
        </Logger>
    </loggers>
</configuration>
```

I am getting logging and data to `catalina.out` but the rest of the files are not getting created. 
Couldn't figure out the silly mistake I might be doing here?
and How do I create one more file which can have the appended logs of `debug-log,trace-log,error-log` only.

Comment: Is your catalina.base defined?

Comment: @muasif80, yes. it's defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your config:

`Console` appenders shouldn't have an `append` attribute.  Removing that should fix your config.

Additionally the `additivity` attribute on the `Root` logger is unnecessary. It does nothing, as there is no higher logger to add to.

You should definitely have seen a line like the following in your output, warning you about the bad config:

`ERROR Console contains an invalid element or attribute "append"`